# A rich person who collects zakat for the poor is entitled to receive from zakat?

Tags: sharia, sunni, fatwa, hanafi

> [*Quran/9/60*](http://quran.com/9/60) *- Sahih International*
> Zakah expenditures are only for
>   the poor and for the needy and **for those employed to collect
>   [zakah]** and for bringing hearts together [for Islam] and for freeing
>   captives [or slaves] and for those in debt and for the cause of Allah
>   and for the [stranded] traveler - an obligation [imposed] by Allah .
>   And Allah is Knowing and Wise.

What does the bold bit mean, sounds as if a millionaire who collects zakat for the poor and needy is entitled to receive zakat, as it doesn't seem to say `for those poor who are employeed to collect zakat`, it just says `for those employed to collect zakat`?

I understand that reading the quran in English can lose it's actual meaning, which is why reason why I am asking for clarification.

Anyone know of a respectable sunni/hanafi fatwa/hadith about this?

Comment: God willing I'll work it into a proper answer when I have time, but the following fatwa covers your question: http://spa.qibla.com/issue_view.asp?HD=1&ID=2469&CATE=5

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways zakat CAN be used is as a compensation of the service to the person collecting the zakat. Just like any other job, it will be considered as a payment. In some countries, it is institutionalized. This will make the institution self-sustaining and withstand coercion from other government departments.

A rich person can choose to provide this service for free, if he wants to.